# Script to return array for scripted metric aggregation from combine

Tags: elasticsearch

For [scripted metric aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)  , in the example shown in the documentation , the combine script returns a single number.

Instead here , can i pass an array or hash ?
I tried doing it , though it did not return any error , i am not able to access those values from reduce script.
In reduce script per shard i am getting an instance when converted to string read as 'Script2$_run_closure1@52ef3bd9'

Kindly let me know , if this can be accomplished in any way.

Answer (score 0):

At least for `Elasticsearch` version 1.5.1 you can do so.

For example, we can modify `Elasticsearch` example ([scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)) to receive an average profit (profit divided by number of transactions):

```python
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "avg_profit": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "_agg['transactions'] = []",
                "map_script": "if (doc['type'].value == \"sale\") { _agg.transactions.add(doc['amount'].value) } else { _agg.transactions.add(-1 * doc['amount'].value) }",
                "combine_script": "profit = 0; num_of_transactions = 0; for (t in _agg.transactions) { profit += t; num_of_transactions += 1 }; return [profit, num_of_transactions]",
                "reduce_script": "profit = 0; num_of_transactions = 0; for (a in _aggs) { profit += a[0] as int; num_of_transactions += a[1] as int }; return profit / num_of_transactions as float"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: this is just a demo for an array in the combine script, you can calculate average easily without using any arrays.

The response will look like:

```python
"aggregations" : {
    "avg_profit" : {
        "value" : 42.5
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use results of such aggregation in terms aggregations (as a sub aggregation) you can't order by its results. This is an open ticket https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486 and it could be resolved in Elasticsearch 2.0.0